# Set day, month and year of a python time_struct without changing the time

Tags: python, time

How can I set day, month, and year of a python time_struct without changing the time which is already in.

The time is specified by the user and assumed to be a time of the current day. This code converts the given string to a time_struct, but sets the date to 1/1/1900:

```
from time import strptime
self._alarmTime = strptime(self._frame.txtAlarmTime.text(), '%H:%M:%S')
```

I now want to replace this 1/1/1900 with some kind of `today()`.

It sounds simple, but I have no idea at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) (which is returned by `time.strptime` / `time.localtime`) behaves like tuple. So you can do following:

```
>>> alarm_time = time.strptime('23:46:00', '%H:%M:%S')
>>> today = time.localtime()
>>> time.struct_time(today[:3] + alarm_time[3:])
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=8,
                 tm_hour=23, tm_min=46, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0,
                 tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.combine( datetime.today().date(),
                  datetime.strptime('23:46:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
                )
```